# JSF：Bean間で情報の受け渡しをする

Tags: java, jsf

JSFでBean同士で値を受け渡す方法を探しています。
A.xhtmlが呼ばれ,commandButtonが押されるとABeanのhoge()が実行され、this.valueに値が代入されます。その後、B.xhtmlに遷移します。
B.xhtmlはBBeanと結びついており、@PostConstructがついたinit()は画面が描画される前に実行されます。この時ABean.hoge()で代入された値を取得したいです。

**A.xhtml**

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="送信" action="#{ABean.hoge()}"/>
```

**ABean**

```
public String hoge() {
        this.value = "test";
        return "B.xhtml";
    }
```

**BBean**

```
@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ここでABeanで代入したthis.valueの値を取得したい。
        String test;
    }
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ABean**

```
public String hoge() {
    FacesContext
        .getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getFlash()
        .put("key", "value");
    return "B.xhtml";
}
```

**BBean**

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    String test = FacesContext
        .getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getFlash()
        .get("key");
}
```